# Itext 5 - detached Signature - variable byte[] returned by getRangeStream()

Tags: itext, digital-signature

I don't understand why the inputStream returned by the getRangeStream() is different at each code iteration on the same file. Normally, it should return "the document bytes that are hashable when using external signatures" which means for me that for the same input file, the same byte array should be returned. But it's not...

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(inPdfFile), null);
    AcroFields acroFields = pdfReader.getAcroFields();
    boolean hasSignature = acroFields.getSignatureNames().size() > 0;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(pdfReader, byteArrayOutputStream, '\0', null, hasSignature);
    pdfStamper.setXmpMetadata(pdfReader.getMetadata());

    PdfSignatureAppearance pdfSignatureAppearance = pdfStamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    PdfSignature pdfSignature = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    pdfSignature.setReason("reason");
    pdfSignature.setLocation("location");
    pdfSignature.setContact("contact");
    pdfSignatureAppearance.setCryptoDictionary(pdfSignature);

    // certify the pdf, if requested
   /* if (certificationLevel > 0) {
        // check: at most one certification per pdf is allowed
        if (pdfReader.getCertificationLevel() != PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED)
            throw new Exception("Could not apply -certlevel option. At most one certification per pdf is allowed, but source pdf contained already a certification.");
        pdfSignatureAppearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED);
    }*/
    pdfSignatureAppearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED);

    HashMap<PdfName, Integer> exc = new HashMap<PdfName, Integer>();
    exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new Integer(30000 * 2 + 2));

    pdfSignatureAppearance.preClose(exc);

    InputStream rangeStream = pdfSignatureAppearance.getRangeStream();
```

Answer (score 1):

An integrated pdf signature is not simply appended as-is to an existing pdf but it is the value of a signature form field (together with some meta information). And an interoperable such signature must sign everything but the space reserved for it in the signature field value.

Whenever you try and sign an existing pdf, therefore, it usually has to be prepared: if there is no form structure in the pdf yet, the form structure must be added. If there is no empty signature form field yet, such a form field must be added. And the signature value must be prepared, in particular with the signing time.

Whenever you create or update a pdf, an ID is generated, a creation or modification time is determined, and these data are added to the created/updated pdf.

Thus, your code in each run manipulates the source pdf, so the resulting pdfs have distinct IDs, modification times and signing times. And as the signature signs everything but its place holder, it also signs these variable data.

Consequentially the hash differs in each run.

---

For further details read [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) and the articles referenced from there.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. So i understand that the metadata and the form fields for signature are included in the data which are returned when call pdfSignatureAppearance .getRangeStream() . If i save the document in that state (prepared PDF to receive a detached signature but without integration of the real detached signature), how can i retrieve the hash provided by the getRangeStream(), if i reopen this saved pdf version.

Comment: @jokon *"how can i retrieve the hash provided by the getRangeStream(), if i reopen this saved pdf version"* - See the iText signature tutorial example [C4_09_DeferredSigning](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5JS/repos/tutorial/browse/signatures/src/main/java/signatures/chapter4/C4_09_DeferredSigning.java), the method `emptySignature` "signs" without injecting a signature container, leaving the placeholder empty, and `createSignature` afterwards works on the output PDF of that first method, retrieves and hashes the range stream, generates a signature, and injects it.